# MySQL Query Comparing DateTime not give the right row

Tags: mysql

`dosen_schedule_datetimestart` , `dosen_schedule_datetimeend` , `academic_schedule_datetimestart` , `academic_schedule_datetimeend`is formatted in `DATETIME` Format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`

This was my MySQL Query, so what i want to do is SELECT Row that `Today` is still in between  `datetimestart` and `datetimeend` And `TIME` of `datetimestart` is less than 15 minutes compared to current time

But it doesnt work, and i also comparing `academic_schedule_dow` with Today's DOW

Any Idea?

```
$checkdosenschedule = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT dosen_schedule_table.*, dosen_table.*, TIME(dosen_schedule_table.dosen_schedule_datetimestart) AS dosen_schedule_checkstart FROM dosen_schedule_table 
                                        INNER JOIN dosen_table 
                                        ON dosen_table.dosen_id = dosen_schedule_table.dosen_id 
                                        WHERE (dosen_schedule_status = 'Active' AND dosen_subs_id != '' ) AND ((DATE(dosen_schedule_datetimestart) >= CURDATE() AND DATE(dosen_schedule_datetimeend) >= CURDATE()) AND (TIME(dosen_schedule_datetimestart) > (NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)))");

$checkacademicschedule = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT academic_schedule_table.*, dosen_table.* FROM academic_schedule_table 
                                    INNER JOIN dosen_table 
                                    ON dosen_table.dosen_id = academic_schedule_table.dosen_id 
                                    WHERE ((academic_schedule_status = 'Active' AND dosen_subs_id != '' ) AND academic_schedule_dow = DAYOFWEEK(NOW())) AND ((DATE(academic_schedule_datetimestart) >= CURDATE() AND DATE(academic_schedule_datetimeend) >= CURDATE()) AND (TIME(academic_schedule_datetimestart) > (NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)))");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using DATE(NOW()) instead of CURDATE()
Also you are checking the range with same sign of greater then equal to.
If you want to check in between, use >= for start and <= for end.